# Pass MVVM Prism navigation arguments to Xamarin Master-Detail Detail page

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, xamarin.forms, prism

**PROBLEM**

Hey hey hey SO.

I have a master detail page app using mvvm prism. Once a user logs into my app they are taken from the login page to the master page. I want to pass navigation params from my login page to the user **detail page** nested inside my master page. . . but the detail page is nested in the XAML of the master page so having issues properly passing the arguments.

**APP STRUCTURE**

*master-page.xaml* nice little ui right here to render the menu and the user page once the user logs in

```
<MasterDetailPage.Master>
        <pages:HamburgerMenu x:Name="HamburgerMenu" />
    </MasterDetailPage.Master>
    <MasterDetailPage.Detail>
        <NavigationPage>
            <x:Arguments>
                <pages:UserPage x:Name="UserPage" />
            </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage>
    </MasterDetailPage.Detail>
```

*app.xaml.cs* entry point for the app rendering the LoginPage **which is not a part of the menu items or in any way associated with the master detail page** it just has a method that will navigate the user to the master detail page

```
protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MainPage = new LoginPage();
    }
```

*login-page-viewmodel.cs* logging in and passing the trying to pass some user info from my database to the master page which has the nested detail page containing the data bound user name field.

```
public NavigationParameters np = new NavigationParameters();

    // magic code everywhere

    private async void LoginAsync()
        {
            var user = await LoginAttemptAsync(_awsomePassword);

            np.Add("UserName", user.name);

            await _navigationService.NavigateAsync("MasterPage", np);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think changing the navigation string to include a NavigationPage and my UserPage fixed it. Waiting for others feedback. Accepting as right answer for now.

**BUGGY CODE**

*login-page-viewmodel.cs*

```
public NavigationParameters np = new NavigationParameters();

    // magic code everywhere

    private async void LoginAsync()
        {
            var user = await LoginAttemptAsync(_awsomePassword);

            np.Add("UserName", user.name);

            await _navigationService.NavigateAsync("MasterPage", np);
        }
```

**FIXED BUT NOT BEST PRACTICE**

*** When using Prism, you should build up your navigation stack via the URI. This also lets Prism resolve your views so you can inject dependencies into them if necessary )**

*login-page-viewmodel.cs*

```
public NavigationParameters np = new NavigationParameters();

    // magic code everywhere

    private async void LoginAsync()
        {
            var user = await LoginAttemptAsync(_awsomePassword);

            np.Add("UserName", user.name);

            await _navigationService.NavigateAsync("MasterPage/Navigation/UserPage", np);
        }
```

Waiting for feedback from others.

Comment: you shouldn't specify the Detail in XAML, that should come from the Navigation URI

Comment: I've seen the docs specify the Detail in XAML https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/navigation/master-detail-page/ using ```<local:ContactsPage />```. is that not best practice?

Comment: No. When using Prism, you should build up your navigation stack via the URI. This also lets Prism resolve your views so you can inject dependencies into them if necessary.

Comment: Perfect I'm going to refactor ASAP. so then what does in place of the Detail in XAML, some data bound property?

Comment: Nothing. The Detail will be empty.

Comment: So remove `<x:Arguments>` and just use the NavigationPage object moving forward?

Comment: Delete the entire MasterDetilPage.Detail element from your XAML.